# How to get access to the selected element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, d3.js

I use d3.js and I created an "option" window that allows me to choose between the index `i` of some elements of, let's say, an array with the length of 4 elements. The user Andrew Reid helped with this code in another thread, so all credits to him:

```
var data = [10,20,30,40];

var color = d3.schemeCategory10; // color array built in

//// Add the select and options:
var select = d3.select('body')
  .append('select')
  .on('change',function() { update(this.value) });
  
var start = select.append('option')
  .html("select: ");
  
var options = select.selectAll('.option')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .attr('class','option')
  .attr('value',function(d,i) { return i; })
  .html(function(d,i) { return i; });


  
//// Add the circles (and svg)
var svg = d3.selectAll('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',500)
  .attr('height',200);
  
var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
  .attr('cy',50)
  .attr('r',10)
  .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });
  
  
// Update everything:
function update(i) {
  data.splice(i,1); // remove that element.
  
  // Update and remove option from the select menu:
  options.data(data).exit().remove();
  
  // Remove that circle:
  circles.data(data).exit().remove(); 
  
  circles.attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });
  
  // reset the select menu:
  start.property('selected','selected');
}
```

With the help of the  line  `.html(function(d,i) { return i; });` the "option" window shows up the indexes and allows me to click on it.

My goal:

For example the "option" window shows up the numbers of the indexes:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

Now I click on the index "2" and i want to use that index "2" in other functions. My question is, how can I save that clicked number in a variable `a` and use this variable, for example, in a splice function:

```
data.splice(i, a)
```

In the code currently the splice function is `data.splice(i,1)`.

Comment: Where do you perform this `array.splice(i, a)`?  Is it on the click event of the option?  This question looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hey Mark, it is not a click event of teh option. It is a seperate outside function.

Comment: @DerickKolln it's impossible to help you without seeing how the event handler calls the other function. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on the **minimum**!) code.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not following this: it's slice or splice? (they are different). And you are **already** passing the index `i` correctly! That number `a` is not the index.

Comment: It is splice, sorry for confusion. Yeah, i know, that it is correctly, but my goal is to click a number on that "option" window based on the index (0,1,2,3) and then the splice function uses the chosen number automatically to remove this number of elements. For example: If i click on "4" in the "option" window, then it should be automatically `data.splice(i, 4)`. That's  why i am looking for a way to store the clicked index number in a variable `a`. And the result of the splice function would be `data.splice(i, a) `.

Comment: Are you looking to take two values (i,a) from one select menu every change (which may be problematic if you chose any value that is over half as large as the data array length), or simply take either a value or index from a select menu and store it in a variable for later ("Now i click on the index "2" and i want to use that index "2" in other functions")? With the latter option, is there an associated trigger of a function? Apologize for my denseness, I'll blame it on something to do with daylight savings time kicking in where I'm at.

Comment: No need to apologise, Andrew. I am happy for anyone who spends his freetime to help bad programmers like me. I am looking for the latter option with a index only. There is no associated trigger of a function written now, because i thought that a solution could be a simple storage in a global variable. But maybe i could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the option text to your update function from your onchange function as:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
```

So you'd end up with:

```
var select = d3.select('body')
  .append('select')
  .on('change',function() { update(this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex].text) }); // note: since you are setting value equal to the index, you can also use this.value instead of this.selectedIndex

function update(i, a) {
  data.splice(i,a);
  ...
}
```

How this works: in your code you use d3 to append an HTML `select` element ([Select object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp)) with several HTML `option` elements ([Option object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp)) in it.

Then on the `select` element, the `onchange` function (which is a [standard event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) of the `select` element) then passes the `select` element to its function handler, so in that function `this` represents the actual `select` element, and therefore `this.value` ([Select value property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp)) corresponds to the value of the `select` element (i.e. the `value` of the currently selected `option` in the `select` element).

The `options` property of the `select` element, i.e. `this.options` ([Select options collection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp)), gets you a list of all of the `option` elements within that `select`. Using the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element, i.e. `this.selectedIndex` ([Select selectedIndex property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)), you can grab the currently selected `option` element from the list as `this.options[this.selectedIndex]`.

Since the `this.options` collection is a list of *Option elements* ([Option object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp)), to get the actual text of that `option` you can use `.text` on it. And that's how you end up with `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried it but it did not work. I just looked at the definition and it says "The selectedIndex property returns the index number of the selected option in that instance of a select box." My question is, when using  `selectedIndex`, is there HTML and a select box required? Because in my code both is not used.

Comment: I think you need to append your options to your select.

Comment: I think it is already appended in the code or you mean a different thing?
  `var options = select.selectAll('.option')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('option')`

Comment: Your idea was very great, i just wonder if there is another solution?

Comment: Hm yeah I see you're right. When you tried using selectedIndex what happened? Did you get an error of some kind?

Comment: Ok I think I found the issue! My answer was slightly off. It should be `this.options[selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: Wow, thank you Erika, this works great. Can you explain me, what is the trick behind it when you add `.text`? I have not understood it right i guess.

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer with the `.text` fix as well as an explanation of how it all works. If it answers your question, it'd be great if you could mark my answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it :)

Comment: Yes, i just accepted it. Can i ask you maybe for a short explanation of that using of `.text`.?

Comment: Thanks! And it's literally just a built in property of the HTML option object - see [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_text.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_text.asp)

Comment: oh wow, so "Return the text of the selected option in a drop-down list" works for numbers also. Thanks so much!