# Swap a D3.js created drop down menu into a HTML created drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, drop-down-menu

In this code (based on this example [How to make the circles disappear based on keyboard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613736/how-to-make-the-circles-disappear-based-on-keyboard-input/42615247?noredirect=1#comment72658398_42615247)), i can click on a number of the drop menu and let circles disappear.

```
var data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];

var color = d3.schemeCategory10; // color array built in

//// Add the select and options:
var select = d3.select('body')
  .append('select')
  .on('change',function() { update(this.value) });

var start = select.append('option')
  .html("select: ");

var options = select.selectAll('.option')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .attr('class','option')
  .attr('value',function(d,i) { return i; })
  .html(function(d) { return d; });



//// Add the circles (and svg)
var svg = d3.selectAll('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',500)
  .attr('height',200);

var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
  .attr('cy',50)
  .attr('r',10)
  .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });


// Update everything:
function update(i) {
  data.splice(i,1); // remove that element.

  // Update and remove option from the select menu:
  options.data(data).exit().remove();

  // Remove that circle:
  circles.data(data).exit().remove(); 

  circles.attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });

  // reset the select menu:
  start.property('selected','selected');
}
```

In this code above the drop down menu was created with D3.js only and no HTML.

Now i want to use have the same behavoiur but a drop menu that is created by HTML so i changed the code alittle bit into this:

```
 <select id = "opts">
    <option value="ds1">1</option>
    <option value="ds2">2</option> 
    <option value="ds3">3</option>

      </select> 
    <script>
    var data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];

    var color = d3.schemeCategory10; // color array built in

   var select = d3.select('#opts')
  .append('select')
  .on('change',function() { update(this.value) });

    //// Add the circles (and svg)
    var svg = d3.selectAll('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',500)
      .attr('height',200);

    var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
      .attr('cy',50)
      .attr('r',10)
      .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });


    // Update everything:
    function update(i) {
      data.splice(i,1); // remove that element.

      // Update and remove option from the select menu:
      options.data(data).exit().remove();

      // Remove that circle:
      circles.data(data).exit().remove(); 

      circles.attr('cx',function(d,i) { return i * 30 + 50; })
        .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; });

      // reset the select menu:
      start.property('selected','selected');
    }
```

Unfortunally it did not work. Can someone help and give me a hint, what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating the drop down in the HTML, you don't need to append anything using D3.

Thus, drop this:

```
var select = d3.select('#opts')
    .append('select')
    .on('change',function() { update(this.value) });
```

And simply add an event listener to the dropdown:

```
d3.select("#opts").on("change", function() {
    //code here
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
d3.select("#opts").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<select id="opts">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option value="ds1">1</option>
  <option value="ds2">2</option>
  <option value="ds3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello Gerardo, with you, it is always a pleasure. Answers are always on point. The code works fine, thanks so much. In the old code, it was possible to update the entries of the drop down menu: `options.data(data).exit().remove();` But in your solution, it is not anymore. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But, again, as this is *another* issue, please post *another* question! The title can be *"updating HTML dropdown with D3"* or something like that. I have a policy: just one issue per question. :-) And this is good to the OP too: if you ask another question in the comments, I am the only one reading it. But if you ask it as a new post, **everybody** is gonna read it.